# Asserting successive calls to a mock method

Tags: python, mocking

Mock has a [helpful `assert_called_with()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with). However, as far as I understand this only checks the *last* call to a method.
If I have code that calls the mocked method 3 times successively, each time with different parameters, how can I assert these 3 calls with their specific parameters?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use the [`Mock.call_args_list` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) to compare parameters to previous method calls. That in conjunction with [`Mock.call_count` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_count) should give you full control.

Comment: `assert_has_calls` only checks if the expected calls have been done, but not if that are the only ones.

Answer (score 307):

`assert_has_calls` is another approach to this problem.

From the docs:

> **assert_has_calls** *(calls, any_order=False)*
>
> assert the mock has been
>   called with the specified calls. The mock_calls list is checked for
>   the calls.
>
> If any_order is False (the default) then the calls must be sequential.
>   There can be extra calls before or after the specified calls.
>
> If any_order is True then the calls can be in any order, but they must
>   all appear in mock_calls.

Example:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import call, Mock
>>> mock = Mock(return_value=None)
>>> mock(1)
>>> mock(2)
>>> mock(3)
>>> mock(4)
>>> calls = [call(2), call(3)]
>>> mock.assert_has_calls(calls)
>>> calls = [call(4), call(2), call(3)]
>>> mock.assert_has_calls(calls, any_order=True)
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls

Comment: A bit weird they chose to add a new "call" type for which they could also have just used a list or a tuple...

Comment: @jaapz It subclasses `tuple`: `isinstance(mock.call(1), tuple)` gives `True`. They also added some methods and attributes.

Comment: Early versions of Mock used a plain tuple, but it turns out to be awkward to use. Each function call receives a tuple of (args, kwargs), so to check that "foo(123)" was called correctly, you need to "assert mock.call_args == ((123,), {})", which is a mouthful compared to "call(123)"

Comment: What do you do when on each instance of call you expect a different return value ?

Comment: @CodeWithPride it looks more a job for `side_effect`

Comment: Thanks @Pigueiras .. I figured it out. But now I have another issue, I have a function that modifies one of the objects passes to it as argument and I later use that object to call another function. How do I test this scenario ? I tried using side_effect for that too, but looks like side_effect is called before mock checks for the arguments being passed to actual call, so its failing the test. Thanks

Comment: @CodeWithPride could you give me an example with some code, please? Maybe you can open a new question with it :)

Comment: Handy that you can pass `any_order=True` :)

Comment: I think there may be a bug with `assert_has_calls`. It started splitting up the input string and placing newlines in random places... I used `assert_any_call` instead and it worked like a charm. (tested with python 3.9, pytest-mock 3.6.1)

Comment: That sounds like a bug in your code, not with assert_has_calls.

Comment: This can be combined with an assertion on `call_count` to ensure the mock is called with exactly the specified calls. In your example, the following will ensure mock is not called with an additional calls than those specified:
mock.assert_has_calls([call(1), call(2), call(3), call(4)])
assert mock.call_count == 4

Answer (score 182):

Usually, I don't care about the order of the calls, only that they happened. In that case, I  combine [`assert_any_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_any_call) with an assertion about [`call_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_count).

```
>>> import mock
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> m(1)
<Mock name='mock()' id='37578160'>
>>> m(2)
<Mock name='mock()' id='37578160'>
>>> m(3)
<Mock name='mock()' id='37578160'>
>>> m.assert_any_call(1)
>>> m.assert_any_call(2)
>>> m.assert_any_call(3)
>>> assert 3 == m.call_count
>>> m.assert_any_call(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[python path]\lib\site-packages\mock.py", line 891, in assert_any_call
    '%s call not found' % expected_string
AssertionError: mock(4) call not found
```

I find doing it this way to be easier to read and understand than a large list of calls passed into a single method.

If you do care about order or you expect multiple identical calls, [`assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) might be more appropriate.

### Edit

Since I posted this answer, I've rethought my approach to testing in general. I think it's worth mentioning that if your test is getting this complicated, you may be testing inappropriately or have a design problem. Mocks are designed for testing inter-object communication in an object oriented design. If your design is not objected oriented (as in more procedural or functional), the mock may be totally inappropriate. You may also have too much going on inside the method, or you might be testing internal details that are best left unmocked. I developed the strategy mentioned in this method when my code was not very object oriented, and I believe I was also testing internal details that would have been best left unmocked.

Comment: @jpmc26 could you elaborate more on your edit? What do you mean by 'best left unmocked'? How else would you test if a call has been made within a method

Comment: @memo Often, it is better to let the real method be called. If the other method is broken, it might break the test, but the value of avoiding that is smaller than the value of having a simpler, more maintainable test. The best times to mock are when the external call to the other method is *what you want to test* (Usually, this means some kind of result is passed into it and the code under test doesn't return a result.) or the other method has external dependencies (database, websites) you want to eliminate. (Technically, the last case is more of a stub, and I would hesitate to assert on it.)

Comment: @jpmc26 mocking is useful when you would like to avoid dependency injection or some other method of runtime strategy choosing.
like you mentioned, testing inner logic of methods, without calling external services, and more importantly, without being environment aware (a no no for good code to have `do() if TEST_ENV=='prod' else dont()`), is achieved easily by mocking the way you suggested. a side effect of this is being to maintain tests per versions (say code changes between google search api v1 and v2, your code will test version 1 no matter what)

Comment: @DanielDubovski Most of your testing should be input/output based. That's not always possible, but if it's not possible most of the time, you probably have a design problem. When you need some value returned that normally comes from another piece of code and you want to cut a dependency, a stub will usually do. Mocks are only necessary when you need to verify that some state modifying function (probably with no return value) is called. (The difference between a mock and a stub is that you don't assert on a call with a stub.) Using mocks where stubs will do makes your tests less maintainable.

Comment: @jpmc26 isn't calling an external service a kind of output? of course you can refactor out the code that builds the message to be sent and test it instead of asserting the call params, but IMHO, it's pretty much the same.
How would you suggest to redesign calling external API's ?I agree that mocking should be cut down to a minimum, all Im saying is you cant go around testing the data you send to external services to make sure the logic is behaving as expected.

Comment: @DanielDubovski Actually, you can. Create a function that builds the arguments to the service. Create a function that takes those arguments as input, makes the request, and returns the output. Now have another function that accepts that output as an argument. Unit test the argument builder and the service output user, and don't test the service caller. 100% coverage isn't an absolute requirement. Each unit test should provide more value (confidence that it works, detection of bugs) than cost (maintainability, etc.).

Answer (score 26):

I always have to look this one up time and time again, so here is my answer.

### Asserting multiple method calls on different objects of the same class

Suppose we have a heavy duty class (which we want to mock):

```
In [1]: class HeavyDuty(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         import time
   ...:         time.sleep(2)  # <- Spends a lot of time here
   ...:     
   ...:     def do_work(self, arg1, arg2):
   ...:         print("Called with %r and %r" % (arg1, arg2))
   ...:
```

here is some code that uses two instances of the  `HeavyDuty` class:

```
In [2]: def heavy_work():
   ...:     hd1 = HeavyDuty()
   ...:     hd1.do_work(13, 17)
   ...:     hd2 = HeavyDuty()
   ...:     hd2.do_work(23, 29)
   ...:
```

Now, here is a test case for the `heavy_work` function:

```
In [3]: from unittest.mock import patch, call
   ...: def test_heavy_work():
   ...:     expected_calls = [call.do_work(13, 17),call.do_work(23, 29)]
   ...:     
   ...:     with patch('__main__.HeavyDuty') as MockHeavyDuty:
   ...:         heavy_work()
   ...:         MockHeavyDuty.return_value.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)
   ...:
```

We are mocking the `HeavyDuty` class with `MockHeavyDuty`. To assert method calls coming from every `HeavyDuty` instance we have to refer to `MockHeavyDuty.return_value.assert_has_calls`,  instead of `MockHeavyDuty.assert_has_calls`.   In addition, in the list of `expected_calls` we have to specify which method name we are interested in asserting calls for.  So our list is made of calls to `call.do_work`, as opposed to simply `call`.

Exercising the test case shows us it is successful:

```
In [4]: print(test_heavy_work())
None
```

If we modify the `heavy_work` function, the test fails and produces a helpful error message:

```
In [5]: def heavy_work():
   ...:     hd1 = HeavyDuty()
   ...:     hd1.do_work(113, 117)  # <- call args are different
   ...:     hd2 = HeavyDuty()
   ...:     hd2.do_work(123, 129)  # <- call args are different
   ...:     

In [6]: print(test_heavy_work())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
(traceback omitted for clarity)

AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call.do_work(13, 17), call.do_work(23, 29)]
Actual: [call.do_work(113, 117), call.do_work(123, 129)]
```

### Asserting multiple calls to a function

To contrast with the above, here is an example that shows how to mock multiple calls to a function:

```
In [7]: def work_function(arg1, arg2):
   ...:     print("Called with args %r and %r" % (arg1, arg2))

In [8]: from unittest.mock import patch, call
   ...: def test_work_function():
   ...:     expected_calls = [call(13, 17), call(23, 29)]    
   ...:     with patch('__main__.work_function') as mock_work_function:
   ...:         work_function(13, 17)
   ...:         work_function(23, 29)
   ...:         mock_work_function.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)
   ...:    

In [9]: print(test_work_function())
None
```

There are two main differences.  The first one is that when mocking a function we setup our expected calls using `call`,  instead of using `call.some_method`.  The second one is that we call `assert_has_calls` on `mock_work_function`, instead of on `mock_work_function.return_value`.

Comment: Just wanted you to know this helped me a lot.
Thank you!